# Counting rows with unique ID in R studio with length(unique)

Tags: r, unique

I have a dataset with people's IDs (some people (IDs) have multiple rows) and risks (transcribed in a number between 1 and 7, and some NA) and I wanted to count the number of people in each risk group, without counting the same person twice. 
When creating a subset containing only 1 row/person, I obtain a certain number of people for each group. However, when I use this function (for each risk group):

`length(unique(data$person_id[data$RISK==1])`

it seems like I get one extra person in each risk group (so 7 extra people in total). 
Does someone have an explanation for this? Do I have to do -1 each time I use this function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()`

Comment: `library(dplyr)` 
`data %>% group_by(RISK) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(person_id)) %>% ungroup()`